# How can I make these buttons obviously clickable?

Tags: buttons, click

I am building an installer in VB.NET in Windows Forms, and am currently adding a final few things such as objects on the About and Preferences pages.

I *know* the buttons are clickable, but the user may not:

[image]

[image]

I'm thinking that the user may interpret the buttons as *steps* in the installation process, and that they go to the Preferences page when they click 'Install'.

The current page is represented by the button being *white*:

[image]

whilst deactivated pages are represented by the button being *grey*:

[image]

How can I make these buttons look obviously clickable whilst being discrete?

I am unable to have 'fade-in, fade-out' effects due to technical restrictions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easiest solution would be to add an underline to inactive links/buttons. If you separate tabs with literally one pixel of white space, they will also look more like clickable tabs.

I also noticed that you didn't respect visual hierarchy, and your CTA got lost and the component thus doesn't look whole (which contributes to tabs not looking like tabs).

[image]